# I can see TA-Lib at anaconda but cant use at pycharm

Tags: python, ta-lib

I ve downloaded anaconda and pycharm. When I have updated Anaconda I can see `TA-Lib` at Conda. But when I am trying to import at PyCharm it can not import. How can I fix this problem?

```
sqlalchemy                1.2.7            py36ha85dd04_0
sqlite                    3.29.0               he774522_0
statsmodels               0.9.0            py36h452e1ab_0
sympy                     1.1.1            py36h96708e0_0
ta-lib                    0.4.16                   py36_0    masdeseiscaracteres
tblib                     1.3.2            py36h30f5020_0
terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_1
testpath                  0.3.1            py36h2698cfe_0
tk                        8.6.8                hfa6e2cd_0
toolz                     0.9.0                    py36_0
tornado                   5.0.2                    py36_0
tqdm                      4.32.1                     py_0
traitlets                 4.3.2            py36h096827d_0
typing                    3.6.4                    py36_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1           py36h6450c06_0
urllib3                   1.22             py36h276f60a_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_0
wcwidth                   0.1.7            py36h3d5aa90_0
webencodings              0.5.1            py36h67c50ae_1
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py36_0
wheel                     0.31.1                   py36_0
widgetsnbextension        3.2.1                    py36_0
```

That's a part of my `conda list` and I can see `ta-lib` there.

```
C:\Users\>pip install ta-lib
Requirement already satisfied: ta-lib in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.4.16)
```

When I type `pip install` I can see it is ok but when I import in PyCharm I get this error message:

```
 error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

Comment: Is the environment used by `conda` and PyCharm the same?

Comment: might be the same